# Reverse a map in <value, key> format in Golang

Tags: dictionary, go

I have a map for my program that looks like following:

```
fruit_map := map[string]string {
    "apple": "likey",
    "orange": "no likey",
}
```

I would like to reverse it so that it reads the following:

```
{
    "likey": "apple",
    "no likey": "orange",
}
```

There are no duplicates in values. Also, my map is small - about 200 keys. I did not find any built-in method to reverse a map like this. Is there any way to do this fast? I am not much bothered about space complexity, but the solution needs to be fast.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may write a `for` loop to iterate over the key-value pair of original map, and put them in a new map (see function `reverseMap`)

Code@https://play.golang.org/p/5y1gABTpdb8

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fruit_map := map[string]string{
        "apple":  "likey",
        "orange": "no likey",
    }

    reversedMap := reverseMap(fruit_map)
    fmt.Println(reversedMap)
}

func reverseMap(m map[string]string) map[string]string {
    n := make(map[string]string, len(m))
    for k, v := range m {
        n[v] = k
    }
    return n
}
```

Output:

```
map[likey:apple no likey:orange]
```

BTW, it is not idiomatic to name go variable like `fruit_map`, you really should use camel-case, like `fruitMap`.

Comment: Since you expect the size of map `m` to be identical to the size of map `m` (assuming no duplicate values), you might want to use: `n := make(map[string]string, len(m))` to save enough space and avoid reallocations during the loop.

Comment: 90% of development tile in Go seems to be writing loops that perform basic tasks that some standard function should provide.

Answer (score 5):

The other answers offer the simple solution based on handling the map directly.

An alternative solution is to encapsulate a bidirectional map as a self-contained utility, which has the advantage that you could write thorough unit tests for it and then be able to rely on it to operate correctly via a simple API.

Here's [my example implementatio](http://play.golang.org/p/NKlei-6L_2)n (which is incomplete and doesn't yet have the necessary unit tests):

package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    biMap := NewBiMap()
    biMap.Put("apple", "likey")
    biMap.Put("orange", "no likey")
    v, _ := biMap.GetByValue("no likey")
    fmt.Println(v)
}

type BiMap struct {
    ab map[string]string
    ba map[string]string
}

func NewBiMap() *BiMap {
    return &BiMap{make(map[string]string), make(map[string]string)}
}

func (m *BiMap) Put(key, value string) *BiMap {
    m.ab[key] = value
    m.ba[value] = key
    return m
}

func (m *BiMap) GetByKey(key string) (value string, exists bool) {
    value, exists = m.ab[key]
    return
}

func (m *BiMap) GetByValue(value string) (key string, exists bool) {
    key, exists = m.ba[value]
    return
}

func (m *BiMap) Len() int {
    return len(m.ab)
}

func (m *BiMap) DeleteKey(key string) *BiMap {
    value, exists := m.ab[key]
    if exists {
        delete(m.ab, key)
        delete(m.ba, value)
    }
    return m
}

func (m *BiMap) DeleteValue(value string) *BiMap {
    key, exists := m.ba[value]
    if exists {
        delete(m.ab, key)
        delete(m.ba, value)
    }
    return m
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending @Dave C's answer , with generic

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    myMap := map[int]string{
        1: "one",
        2: "two",
        3: "three",
    }

    result := reverseMap(myMap)
    fmt.Println(result)

}

func reverseMap[M ~map[K]V, K comparable, V comparable](m M) map[V]K {
    reversedMap := make(map[V]K)
    for key, value := range m {
        reversedMap[value] = key
    }
    return reversedMap
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right, there is nothing built-in to accomplish this but it is really straightforward:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    fruit_map := map[string]string{
        "apple":  "likey",
        "orange": "no likey",
    }

    //create your new empty map that will hold your reversed contents.
    reversed_fruit_map := make(map[string]string)

    for k, v := range fruit_map{
        reversed_fruit_map[v] = k
    }

    fmt.Println(reversed_fruit_map)
}
```

This outputs the following:

```
map[likey:apple no likey:orange]
```

Check it out on the [playground](http://play.golang.org/p/fLHGXoP7rE).  If this is common you can always extract out into your own function.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a built in function to do that, but it's simple enough with a `for` loop.

```
fruit_map := map[string]string {
    "apple": "likey",
    "orange": "no likey",
}

reversed_map := make(map[string]string)

for key,value := range fruit_map {
    reversed_map[value] = key
}
```

see: http://play.golang.org/p/BQjqUsf9aU

Answer (score 0):

Using a custom type with a `Reverse()` method implemented is another option.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type (
    MapA map[string]string
    MapB map[int]string
)

// Reverse returns a reverse map of the MapA object.
func (m MapA) Reverse() map[string]string {
    n := make(map[string]string, len(m))
    for k, v := range m {
        n[v] = k
    }
    return n
}

// Reverse returns a reverse map of the MapB object.
func (m MapB) Reverse() map[string]int {
    n := make(map[string]int, len(m))
    for k, v := range m {
        n[v] = k
    }
    return n
}

func main() {
    myMapA := &MapA{
        "apple":  "likey",
        "orange": "no likey",
    }
    myMapB := &MapB{
        10: "likey",
        5:  "not sure",
        0:  "no likey",
    }

    fmt.Println(myMapA.Reverse())
    fmt.Println(myMapB.Reverse())
}
```